# Firebase Analytics initialization in Kotlin vs Java

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-analytics

I'm wondering why initialization of Firebase Analytics in Kotlin doesn't need context, but Java does need?

From documentation:

```
Java:
mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(context);

Kotlin:
firebaseAnalytics = Firebase.analytics
```

Comment: It is the same as JAVA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Kotlin version is an extension property. According to the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics#getinstance):

> @NonNull static fun getInstance(@NonNull context: Context): FirebaseAnalytics

Returns the singleton FirebaseAnalytics interface.

---

While the [`analytics`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/analytics/ktx/package-summary), which is an extension property:

> val Firebase.analytics: FirebaseAnalytics

Returns the FirebaseAnalytics instance of the default FirebaseApp.

Comment: Is it ok to use Kotlin version in my own class logger? I mean, I have two options to create my util class to log analytics events: 1. Pass context and use getInstance(); 2. Just use Kotlin version. Any problems with second approach?

Comment: yes if you are already using Kotlin in your application, then just use the extension firebase library